# How to reduce repeated calls to custom event or method to one?

Tags: c#, winforms

If my event/method is called twice before the first call is done, it should react like it was called only once. More than 1 consecutive calls should be reduced to 1.

I believe that this is what the `Control.Invalidate` method in Winforms does.

I have a container control (based on `FlowLayoutPanel`). The controls have an ID number that must be updated when some of them are removed or added (they should have consecutive IDs starting from `1`). The method that updates the IDs is `RefreshDisplay` which may be called more than one time until the execution returns to the main message loop.

**Update 1:**

I think that the `Invalidate` method reduces multiple consecutive calls to it. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) says:

> Invalidates the specified region of the control (adds it to the control's update region, which is the area that will be repainted **at the next paint operation**), and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.

In my case it is a method but I also thought of making it an event with event handlers.

The `RefreshDisplay` method is called when:

1. an item is created or removed (e.g. when one or more rows of a `DataGridView` are deleted);
2. an item in a collection is moved to another position in the same collection;
3. the groups of items inside the collection are changed (e.g. the renaming or removal of a group);
4. when a view is created for the collection (e.g. at the start of the program);
5. when a child of a view is set invisible or visible (the visibility is a part of the model of the child).

The `RefreshDisplay` method (whose consecutive calls I would like to be reduced to 1) is part of an interface that is implemented in these ways:

**1.**

```
public void RefreshDisplay()
{
    SuspendLayout();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ClockDataGridViewRow r in Rows)
    {
        if (r.IsNewRow)
        {
            continue;
        }
        r.HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
        if (!r.MyClockData.FilteredOut)
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    ForceUpdateZoomFactor(ZoomFactor);
    ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

**2.**

```
public void RefreshDisplay()
{
    SuspendLayout();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ClockData td in MyDataFile.ClockCollection.ClocksData)
    {
        foreach (IClockView tv in td.MyTimerViews)
        {
            if (tv is ClockControl tc &&
                tc.GetTimersView() == this)
            {
                tc.SetTagText((i + 1).ToString());
            }
        }
        if (!td.FilteredOut)
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

**3.**

```
public void RefreshDisplay()
{
    MyListView.Items.Clear();
    UpdateListViewImageLists(ZoomPercent);
    ListViewItem it = MyListView.Items.Add("All");
    it.Tag = new Filter()
    {
        ShowActive = true,
        ShowInactive = true,
        ShowTimers = true,
        ShowAlarms = true
    };
    it.ImageIndex = 1;
    ListViewItem itActive = MyListView.Items.Add("Active");
    itActive.Tag = new Filter()
    {
        ShowActive = true,
        ShowInactive = false,
        ShowTimers = true,
        ShowAlarms = true
    };
    itActive.ImageIndex = 2;
    ListViewItem itInactive = MyListView.Items.Add("Inactive");
    itInactive.Tag = new Filter()
    {
        ShowActive = false,
        ShowInactive = true,
        ShowTimers = true,
        ShowAlarms = true
    };
    itInactive.ImageIndex = 3;
    ListViewItem itTimers = MyListView.Items.Add("Timers");
    itTimers.Tag = new Filter()
    {
        ShowActive = true,
        ShowInactive = true,
        ShowTimers = true,
        ShowAlarms = false
    };
    itTimers.ImageIndex = 4;
    ListViewItem itAlarms = MyListView.Items.Add("Alarms");
    itAlarms.Tag = new Filter()
    {
        ShowActive = true,
        ShowInactive = true,
        ShowTimers = false,
        ShowAlarms = true
    };
    itAlarms.ImageIndex = 5;
    int gi = 0;
    foreach (string g in MyDataFile.ClockCollection.Groups)
    {
        ListViewItem item = MyListView.Items.Add(g);
        item.Tag = new Filter()
        {
            ShowActive = true,
            ShowInactive = true,
            ShowAlarms = true,
            ShowTimers = true
        };
        (item.Tag as Filter).GroupIndices.Add(gi);
        Image ico;
        if (MyDataFile.ClockCollection.Groups.Icons.ContainsKey(g))
        {
            // possibly null:
            ico = MyDataFile.ClockCollection.Groups.Icons[g];
        }
        else
        {
            ico = null;
        }
        MyListView.SmallImageList.Images.Add(
            ico ?? new Bitmap(1, 1));
        MyListView.LargeImageList.Images.Add(
            ico ?? new Bitmap(1, 1));
        if (ico != null)
        {
            item.ImageIndex = item.Index + 5;
        }
        else
        {
            item.ImageIndex = 0;
        }
        ++gi;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a starting point, can we see this method?

Comment: I updated the question with details.

Comment: The `Control.Invalidate` call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netframework-4.7.2) tells Windows that the drawing area of the control is _invalid_ and that it needs to be redrawn.  This will eventually cause your code to get a `Paint` event (if you have registered for one).  If you haven't wired up a `Paint` handler, the default Paint routine for the control will redraw the control.  99% of this happens under the covers (it's a Windows thing, not a .NET thing).  I'm not sure why you think that it has to do with bunching calls

Comment: We'd still like to see the code, both the code that raises the event and the event handler.  Are these multiple event calls causing the controls to get the wrong IDs?  Or does the event handler take some time to run?

Comment: @gunnerone I updated the question with more details.